# JAR behaves differently when running in Eclipse or cmd window

Tags: java

I developed a utility in Java and created a runnable JAR.
When I run it in Eclipse using Run --> configuration it does what I want it to do
The same Jar running in cmd does not do what the run in Eclipse does
Any thought why this is happening ?

Thanks
Shimon

Comment: Can you provide some more information? How are they behaving differently? How are you running the jar in cmd? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Though they go through the same functions, they return different results, in my case different XML content. and when I try to update the xml content (I stress - calling the same functions) it does it when running in Eclipse and NOT when running in CMD. I do not get any errors just the result of the run is different. I am using the same JRE version.